# CodeMirror: Is there a way exist search mode by clicking on Esc button

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have been using the following example to add search function to code mirror

```
http://jsfiddle.net/e8zknobh/1/
```

at some point of time I decided to add a feature that by clicking on the `Esc` button I want the search mode to be quit and slightly changed the sample by adding

```
    extraKeys: {
    'Esc': function(cm) {
                $('.cm-searching').removeClass('cm-searching');
  }
}
```

which is not complete exit from search mode because I'm still able to move(Cmd+G) between the elements even though they are not highlighted, moreover in case of multiple code mirrors across the application, every initialization should be extended with `extraKeys`, is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

after digging a bit in search script found the solution

```
extraKeys: {
    'Esc' : function (cm) {
        cm.execCommand('clearSearch');
    }
}
```